# A classic "What am I?"

Tags: riddle, word, poetry

Used to remove or to choose,

remove a letter for a better shot

or used on string

physical I can be yet also cannot

add a letter for a description,

or remove the first one to act

used every day by everyone

and being mean isn't something I lack

What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is

> PICK

Used to remove or to choose,

> Pick can describe the act of removal ("picking flowers") or a tool used to remove (like a pick axe) and can also mean *to choose* from a number of alternatives.

remove a letter for a better shot

> A *pic* is an informal word for a photograph (a camera shot).

or used on string

> A pick is another word for a guitar plectrum, used on the strings of a guitar.

physical I can be yet also cannot

> Some picks are physical (plectrum or axe) and some are not (choice).

add a letter for a description,

> *Spick* is a description meaning clean and tidy

or remove the first one to act

> Not totally sure about this, *ick* is an expression of disgust (possibly used in acting).

used every day by everyone

> Everyone makes choices every day.

and being mean isn't something I lack

> Not being picked for something can seem a bit mean.

Answer (score 0):

> The solution to this riddle seems to be the word "Cut."

> - "Used to remove or to choose, remove a letter for a better shot": When you cut something, you remove part of it. Removing a letter from "cut" gives you "ut," which could be interpreted as a phonetic representation of "you'd," suggesting a better shot or choice.

> - "Or used on string": You can physically cut a string.

> - "Physical I can be yet also cannot": The act of cutting is physical, but the concept or decision to cut is not.

> - "Add a letter for a description, or remove the first one to act": Adding a letter to "cut" could create words like "cute" (a description). Removing the first letter leaves "ut," which is not a word but could imply action.

> - "Used every day by everyone": The concept or action of cutting is a common daily occurrence.

> - "And being mean isn't something I lack": The word "cut" can also be used in a metaphorical sense to suggest a mean action, like cutting remarks.